# Removing margin between Toolbar and nested TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have a `TabLayout` that is inside a `Toolbar`. I wanted to remove the overflow menu (three dots) so I commented out the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods that were auto-generated, to remove the icon (is this the proper way anyway?). Now there is a bit of a margin on the left side of the `TabLayout`. Here is a pic for reference: http://prntscr.com/8gf4c3

I have tried adding a negative margin to the `TabLayout` but that did not seem to work. I'd like the `TabLayout` to completely fill the `Toolbar`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you need to use `Toolbar`?

Comment: @karaokyo What else would you recommend? I was trying to plan for the future and thinking i may want to use a Collapsing Toolbar or some other Toolbar features. I'm open to other ideas though, what did you have in mind?

Comment: Remove the `Toolbar` and just use a `TabLayout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the left part, just use `toolbar.setContentInsetsRelative(0, 0);`

If you want to do the same but for xml, use `android:contentInsetStart/Left="0dp"`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setContentInsetsRelative%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Ah thanks that worked brilliantly for the left & right. Is there a way to do this in the xml layout? Also, can this be done with the top & bottom? I was using negative margins but something like this would be cleaner.

Comment: I edited my answer for your question about xml. For the tom/bottom, have the layout_height that match_parent should be enough.

Comment: Awesome, worked great. A note though: on tablet, there is still a small margin on the left/right sides, not sure why. Thanks!